# How to make a centered menu with a logo image about 200px away from the screens edge

Tags: html, css, menu, frontend

I need something like this, i tried alot but failed lol, im new[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5oEv.png)

Answer (score 0):

flex space between

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">logo</div>
  <div class="center">menu menu menu menu</div>
  <div class="right">anonymous</div>
</div>
```